# bootstrap button text align

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my project I need to make a `bootsrap's` success button with a pretty little wigth. The problem is that the text in this button does not aligned to the center of button. It has to large left padding. So how can I fix it?

PS

```
The picture is something like that:

+------+
|  text|
+------+

I want:

+------+
| text |
+------+
```

code:

```
HTML:

btn1.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-success card_btn");
btn1.innerHTML = "To solitaire";
btn1.onclick = to_solitaire;


CSS:

.btn {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

`

Comment: make sure you have equal padding on both sides and just add text-align: center;

Comment: if you share your code in fiddle, we can easily find a solution for your problem.

Comment: Sorry, did it now. @SureshPonnukalai

Comment: did you try with important like `padding:2px !important`?

Answer (score 0):

Here no need to add `css` for any style in bootstrap, all the styles are in-built

in `btn` class , `text-align:center` as default

For example Use like this:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Text" />
```

Output:

```
+------+
| Text |
+------+
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7413/)

Comment: Thank for answering, but I already has received it and, more over, it doest work your way. Just try to write something like this: `<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Text" style="width: 45px"/>` and Ull see that text isnt in button center

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a glyphicon and text. A simple rearrangement of code and css help tremendously:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default ">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span>
   &nbsp;Upload
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.btn{text-align: left;}
```

My mistake was having the text inside the span. No matter what CSS I applied, nothing would happened. In fact it look Justified more than centered.